# using ASP.NET DLL under php

Tags: php, asp.net, components

i've managed to access com objects with php and i'm wondering if it's also possible with asp.net components? for asp.net, the .dll doesn't require registering on the webserver and will be put into the /bin folder of the current project.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one way is with Phalanger, http://www.php-compiler.net/.  You might also find this article to be useful, http://www.infoq.com/articles/Phalanger.